# Fatal Exception on start up 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n[0].section')'

Tags: react-native, crashlytics

We see on android and iOS a crash that happens on startup that seems to be related to the scrollResonseHandleScroll method. It looks like it is pretty random that's why we were not able to reproduce it but it affects a lot of our users and happens on a daily bases.
We are not sure if this is a problem on our side or in react-native, but so far it was not fixed by any react-native update. I hope someone can help us.

This is one of the log messages and the stack that we see:

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n[0].section'), stack: onViewableItemsChanged@1616:8294 _onViewableItemsChanged@331:1909 value@317:3435 value@317:2836 <unknown>@270:22129 forEach@-1 value@270:22088 _onScroll@270:6507 scrollResponderHandleScroll@282:2289 scrollResponderHandleScroll@-1 _handleScroll@276:3286 p@95:384 b@95:527 T@95:581 w@95:876 ke@95:12621 _@95:2072 <unknown>@95:12968 xe@95:89207 Se@95:12419 Re@95:12808 receiveEvent@95:13217 value@40:3350 <unknown>@40:747 value@40:2610 value@40:719 value@-1
```

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n[0].section'), stack:
onViewableItemsChanged@1616:8294
_onViewableItemsChanged@331:1909
value@317:3435
value@317:2836
<unknown>@270:22129
forEach@-1
value@270:22088
_onScroll@270:6507
scrollResponderHandleScroll@282:2289
scrollResponderHandleScroll@-1
_handleScroll@276:3286
p@95:384
b@95:527
T@95:581
w@95:876
ke@95:12621
_@95:2072
<unknown>@95:12968
xe@95:89207
Se@95:12419
Re@95:12808
receiveEvent@95:13217
value@40:3350
<unknown>@40:747
value@40:2610
value@40:719
value@-1

       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

I'm more than happy to provide more logs and device information if necessary.

### React Native version info:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Memory: 1003.27 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.7.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.7 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.0. - /Users/benwunderlich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.6, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 24, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3
      System Images: android-24 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-R | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-R | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
    Xcode: 11.6/11E708 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_242-release - /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
    Python: 3.7.0 - /Users/benwunderlich/.pyenv/shims/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.2 => 0.63.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Thanks!

Comment: This may be an error in your code. Can you search for the location in your code where you use the errored variable (`n[0].section` or wherever you accessed `section` from an array item) ??

Comment: It looks like there is an array of objects and you want to access the `section` property of the first object. Is `n` is being fetched from the server through some asynchronous call? There might be a possibility that sometimes due to some delay in response you are not able to access objects inside `n`. Try to put the `Array.isArray(n)` check before `n[0].section`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
Yes, it is an array that seems to be undefined, but when you look in the trace it mentions the `onViewableItemsChanged` method that is not part of our code. 
I'm not familiar with the insides of react-native, could this be a method of react-native?